# Origen de la frase "pensando en la inmortalidad del cangrejo"

Tags: modismos

La frase "pensando en la inmortalidad del cangrejo" es muy usada en los paises de habla hispana. Sin embargo, a pesar de entender bien a que se refiere, no puedo encontrar el origen de esta frase.

Comment: El primer registro que encontré fue de 1862: [Don Junípero, Volume 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QtNOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT15&dq="inmortalidad+del+cangrejo") *"... y mucha pa- sadita de peine por el poco pelo que me queda a fuerza de discurrir sobre la inmortalidad del cangrejo..."* ([Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inmortalidad+del+cangrejo&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=21)). Además, Wikipedia tiene [un poema anónimo de 1855](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pensar_en_la_inmortalidad_del_cangrejo).

Comment: Entiendo la implementacion. Pero debe haber una explicacion de porque el cangrejo y porque inmortal.

Comment: Sé que las langostas son conocidas por su longevidad, relacionadas con la (continua) reparación de sus telómeros; pero no soy consciente de que este efecto se extiende a los cangrejos: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_immortality#Lobsters  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobster#Longevity

Comment: Hmm entiendo eso, pero el cangrejo no es longevo, vive entre 3 y 12 años. En dado caso la tortuga vive mucho mas. ¿Porque no pensar en la inmortalidad de la tortuga?

Comment: No encuentro buenas fuentes, pero parece que en la mitología egipcia, el escarabeo simbolizaba la inmortalidad, y el cangrejo se relacionaba con el escarabeo.  Para los griegos, el cangrejo parece haber pasado a este papel.

Comment: Un fragmento de [*La Cristíada*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5WKEsEgxDakC&pg=PA414&dq=inmortal+cangrejo) (1611) por Diego de Ojeda sobre las constelaciones: `A un lado meneábase el Cangrejo, Y era de estrellas su inmortal pellejo.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fui googleando y encontré este pasaje muy interesante sobre esta expresión.  Parece que viene de la mitología griega:

> "La mitología griega cuenta que Zeus platicaba con un cangrejo quien le explicaba que al caminar de lado engañaban al tiempo, lo que los hacía inmortales. La filosofía dice que al no tener consciencia de sí mismo, no es consciente de que su existencia acabará, por lo tanto, es inmortal. Absorto estaba yo en estos pensamientos cuando dieron un giro, un cambio de personaje. Pensaba ahora en la inmortalidad del hombre. ¿Qué pasaría si nuestra existencia fuera infinita?"

Aquí está la referencia:

http://www.ruizhealytimes.com/cultura-para-todos/de-la-inmortalidad-del-cangrejo

Otra referencia interesante:

http://www.pulsodigital.net/2010/02/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-frase-pensando.html

Comment: Esto leí yo también, pero no podía encontrar ningún fuente. El único caso de un cangrejo que conozco en la mitología griega es lo del cangrejo que peleó contra Heracles con la Hidra de Lerna, y por su ayuda se convirtió en la constelación: [Carcinos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcinos).

Comment: @ukemi - Seguí los mismos pasos y llegué a lo mismo. // Karlomanio, ¿has encontrado una base para esta afirmación?

Comment: Me gusta, habrá alguna referencia? Si parece ser el origen de la frase.

Answer (score 2):

En Hamlet existe una referencia a este hecho que quizá explique la relación entre el cangrejo y la inmortalidad:

> *HAMLET*: De calumnias. Aquí dice el malvado satírico, que los viejos tienen la barba blanca, la cara con arrugas, que vierten sus ojos ámbar abundante y goma de ciruelo, y que unen a una gran debilidad de nalgas mucha falta de entendimiento. Todo lo cual, señor mío, aunque yo plena y eficazmente lo creo, no me parece bien hallarlo afirmado en tales términos. *Porque al fin vos seríais sin duda tan joven como yo, si os fuera posible andar hacia atrás como el cangrejo*.

La idea de que el cangrejo camina hacia atrás es errónea pero extendida. Lo que entiendo con la cita es que el cangrejo, al supuestamente "caminar hacia atrás" invertiría el efecto que el tiempo tiene en el resto. En el texto, Hamlet le sugiere a Polonio que un rejuvenecimiento sería posible si pudiese imitar ese animal. Con esto en mente, el cangrejo sería "inmortal" y un tema para reflexionar por horas...

Comment: Creo que la frase está un poco de más, pero la idea que el cangrejo camine hacia atrás causa efecto en el tiempo de este es sin duda algo bastante intrigante. No obstante, lo que quiero saber es más de dónde origina, con quién, cuando.